# How to make custom dialog box with multiple buttons in it?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to make custom dialog box in android as shown in the image.
I want to open a dialog with multiple images and perform action on click event on each images.
Can anybody guide me.
[Custom dialog like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ4u7.jpg)

I want to open the custom dialog when clicked on the 3 dots as shown in the image.

Comment: you can use popup window for showing this type of dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(define your layout here, null);  
         final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
           popupView, 
           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

         Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
         btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  popupWindow.dismiss();
 }});

         popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

}});
```

Comment: because i am very much concerneed relarted to UI

Comment: which LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  you used here are many suggestions in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/FB_White"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/FB_Black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

           <!-- <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Content"
                android:textColor="@color/FB_White"
                android:textSize="12sp" />-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_btncancel"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="CANCEL"
                    android:textColor="@color/FB_Orange"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_btnok"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="OK"
                    android:textColor="@color/FB_Orange"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

**Show alertDialog**   


 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                MainActivity.this);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        dialog.show();

                        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                        txtTitle.setText("Proceed to Logout?");
                        txtTitle.setTypeface(common.setTypefaceRegular());

                        Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                        btnCancel.setText("CANCEL");
                        btnCancel.setTypeface(common.setTypefaceSemiBold());
                        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                        btnOk.setText("OK");
                        btnOk.setTypeface(common.setTypefaceSemiBold());
                        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                deleteLogin();
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.show();
```

Comment: will it show as it is shown in image?
@Punithapriya

Comment: No i just added the sample code you can add the views you want.Its just simple.

Answer (score 0):

On the (...) button click action add the below lines

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);        
    PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null, false));
        popup.setWidth(300);
        popup.setHeight(150);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    popup.show(event);
```

where `R.layout.yourlayout`, mention the layout you need to display in the popup window.